# No such file or directory when adding script to local site-packages

Tags: python-2.7, site-packages

I made my own python module that I want to be able to import from anywhere. The module I created relies of a text file of information in order to run.

I ran `python -m site --user-site`, and created that directory and I put a copy of my module, and the text file into the `site-packages` directory, restarted IDLE and then attempted to import my module. I ran into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import MyModule
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\MyModule.py", line 34, in <module>
    with open('TextFile.txt') as p:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TextFile.txt'
```

This is what my module looked like:

```
import blah

...

with open('TextFile.txt') as p:
    p.read()
```

why is this error happening? The file is in the same directory!

Comment: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` might be relevant to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when you import a site-package, it gets executed in the current directory, not in the `site-packages` directory.

The way you can fix this error is to specify the path to the file you want.
For example, you would change line 34 of MyModule, to match this code:

```
with open('C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\TextFile.txt') as p:
```

Alternatively, you could either change the current directory to `site-packages`, or get a copy of the needed file (in this case `TextFile.txt`) in the current directory as a quick fix without modifying your module.